# Javascript causing memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't for the life of me figure out why loading this page...
http://polyphonic.hannahkingdev.com/work/cowboys-angels or any other video page sometimes causes the browser to hang and then prompts me to stop the script that is causing the browser to slowdown.

If the video is left to run, by the time you go to close the page, the browser is pretty unresponsive. This is the same in FFox, Safari & Chrome.

Any help finding the memory leak would be most appreciated. I am completely stumped on this one.

Many thanks

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(initPage);

// -- Init -- //
function initPage() {
    resizeWork();
    //hoverWorkImg();
};
// -- Pageload -- //
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".animsition").animsition({
        inClass: 'overlay-slide-in-left',
        outClass: 'overlay-slide-out-left',
        inDuration: 1500,
        outDuration: 800,
        linkElement: 'a:not([target="_blank"]):not([href^=#]):not([href^=mailto]:not([href^=tel])',
        loading: true,
        loadingParentElement: 'body', //animsition wrapper element
        loadingClass: 'animsition-loading',
        loadingInner: '', // e.g '<img src="loading.svg" />'
        timeout: false,
        timeoutCountdown: 5000,
        onLoadEvent: true,
        browser: [ 'animation-duration', '-webkit-animation-duration'],
        overlay : true,
        overlayClass : 'animsition-overlay-slide',
        overlayParentElement : 'body',
        transition: function(url){ window.location.href = url; }
    });
});
// -- Navigation -- //
if (document.getElementById('menu-button') !=null) {
    var button = document.getElementById('menu-button');
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu-main-navigation');
    var menuPos = window.innerHeight;
    var menuFixed = false;

    button.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        menu.classList.toggle('navigation--isOpen');
        button.classList.toggle('navigation-button--isOpen');
    })

    updateMenuPosition();
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateMenuPosition);

    // -- Highlight nav -- /
    var $navigationLinks = $('#menu-main-navigation > li > a');
    var $sections = $($("section").get().reverse());
    var sectionIdTonavigationLink = {};
    $sections.each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        sectionIdTonavigationLink[id] = $('#menu-main-navigation > li > a[href="#' + id + '"]');
    });
    function throttle(fn, interval) {
        var lastCall, timeoutId;
        return function () {
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            if (lastCall && now < (lastCall + interval) ) {
                clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                    lastCall = now;
                    fn.call();
                }, interval - (now - lastCall) );
            } else {
                lastCall = now;
                fn.call();
            }
        };
    }
    function highlightNavigation() {
        var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
        $sections.each(function() {
            var currentSection = $(this);
            var sectionTop = currentSection.offset().top;
            if (scrollPosition >= sectionTop) {
                var id = currentSection.attr('id');
                var $navigationLink = sectionIdTonavigationLink[id];
                if (!$navigationLink.hasClass('active')) {
                    $navigationLinks.removeClass('active');
                    $navigationLink.addClass('active');
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    $(window).scroll( throttle(highlightNavigation,100) );
}

function updateMenuPosition(){
    if(menuFixed){
        menu.classList.remove('navigation--white');
        menuPos = menu.offsetTop;
        menu.classList.add('navigation--white');
    } else {
        menuPos = menu.offsetTop;
    }
    updateMenuAttachment();
}

updateMenuAttachment();
window.addEventListener('scroll', updateMenuAttachment);

function updateMenuAttachment(){
    var scrollPos = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    if(!menuFixed && scrollPos >= window.innerHeight - 200){
        menu.classList.add('navigation--white');
        menuFixed = true;
    } else if(menuFixed && scrollPos < window.innerHeight - 200){
        menu.classList.remove('navigation--white');
        menuFixed = false;
    }
}


// -- Smooth scroll to anchor -- /
$('a[href*="#"]')
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (this.hash=="#work") {;
            var offsetT = (target.offset().top)-90;
        } else {
            var offsetT = (target.offset().top);
        }
        if (target.length) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: offsetT
            }, 1000, function() {

            });
        }
    }
});

// -- Back to top -- /
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var offset = 300,
        offset_opacity = 1200,
        scroll_top_duration = 700,
        $back_to_top = $('.cd-top');

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $back_to_top.addClass('cd-is-visible') : $back_to_top.removeClass('cd-is-visible cd-fade-out');
        if( $(this).scrollTop() > offset_opacity ) { 
            $back_to_top.addClass('cd-fade-out');
        }
    });
    $back_to_top.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0 ,
             }, scroll_top_duration
        );
    });

});

// -- Animate -- /
new WOW().init();

// -- Inline all SVGs -- /
jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
    var $img = jQuery(this);
    var imgID = $img.attr('id');
    var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
    var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

    jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
        // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
        var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

        // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
        if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
        }
        // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
        if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
        }

        // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
        $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

        // Check if the viewport is set, if the viewport is not set the SVG wont't scale.
        if(!$svg.attr('viewBox') && $svg.attr('height') && $svg.attr('width')) {
            $svg.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + $svg.attr('height') + ' ' + $svg.attr('width'))
        }

        // Replace image with new SVG
        $img.replaceWith($svg);

    }, 'xml');

});


// -- work grid -- /
function resizeWork() {
    var div = $('.work article');
    div.css('height', div.width() / 1.9);
}
function hoverWorkImg() {
    $('article a').on('mouseenter', function () {
        $(this).find('.imagehover:hidden').fadeIn(700);
        $(this).find('.second:hidden').fadeIn(700);
        $(this).find('.first:visible').fadeOut(700);
    })

    $('article a').on('mouseleave', function () {
        $(this).find('.imagehover:visible').fadeOut(700);
        $(this).find('.second:visible').fadeOut(700);
        $(this).find('.first:hidden').fadeIn(700);
    })
}

// -- Video Page -- /
    function playVideoInPage() {
        showModal(false);
        initPlayer();
        startPlay();
    }
    var $video,
        $playPauseButton,
        $muteButton,
        $seekBar,
        isMouseMove=false,
        $timing;

    function showModal(html) {
        if (html !== false) {
            $('.work-video').html(html).fadeIn();
        }
        else {
            $('.work-video').fadeIn();
        }
        hidePlayerControls();
    }

    function initPlayer() {
        $('#video').css('height', $(window).height());
        $video = $('.video-container'),
            $playPauseButton = $('#play-pause'),
            $muteButton = $('#mute'),
            $seekBar = $('#seek-bar'),
            $timing = $('.timing');
        /*setTimeout('showPlayerControls()', 1500);*/

        $playPauseButton.on('click', function () {
            if ($video.get()[0].paused == true) {
                $video.get()[0].play();
                $playPauseButton.removeClass('paused');
            }
            else {
                $video.get()[0].pause();
                $playPauseButton.addClass('paused');
                $timing.stop(true, true);
            }
        })

        $muteButton.on('click', function () {

            if ($video.get()[0].muted == false) {
                $video.get()[0].muted = true;

                $muteButton.addClass('muted');
            }
            else {
                $video.get()[0].muted = false;
                $muteButton.removeClass('muted');
            }
        })

        $seekBar.on("click", function (e) {
            var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
                widthForOnePercent = $seekBar.width() / 100,
                progress = x / widthForOnePercent,
                goToTime = progress * ($video.get()[0].duration / 100);

            goToPercent(progress)
            $video.get()[0].currentTime = goToTime;
        });

        $video.get()[0].addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
            var value = (100 / $video.get()[0].duration) * $video.get()[0].currentTime;
            goToPercent(value)
        });

    }

    function startPlay() {
        $playPauseButton.click();
    }

    function goToPercent(value) {
        $timing.css('width', value + '%');
    }

    function showPlayerControls() {
        $('.controls').fadeIn();
        isMouseMove=true;
    }

    function hidePlayerControls() {
        $('.controls').fadeOut();
    }

    function hidePlayerControls() {
        setInterval(function() {
            if (!isMouseMove) {
                hidePlayerControls();
            }
            isMouseMove=false;
        }, 4000);

        $(document).mousemove(function (event) {
            isMouseMove=true;
            showPlayerControls();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Don't just post a link to another page. Question should contain the relevant code that produces the issue.

Comment: I would start by investigating the setTimeout and setInterval calls you have.  Your javascript on the page is minified, so anyone who looks at it to help will have a bunch of deciphering to do.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. By any other video page, I meant within the same website using the same JS. I will add the unminified JS above

Comment: Have a read of [mcve].  Work on finding the *minimal* amount of code that reproduces the problem.  If you can't find a solution from that (that act in itself frequently points to the issue) then update question with the minimal code.   There's too much code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is this code here:

```
function hidePlayerControls() {
    setInterval(function() {
        if (!isMouseMove) {
            hidePlayerControls();
        }
        isMouseMove=false;
    }, 4000);
```

so *every* 4 seconds you start a *new interval* (interval = repeat until cancelled).

In the first case, you might like to change this to `setTimeout`

```
function hidePlayerControls() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!isMouseMove) {
            hidePlayerControls();
        }
        isMouseMove=false;
    }, 4000);
```

In the second, you could change this to *cancel* the previous timeout when the mouse moves - this is termed *debouncing* - though usually with a shorter interval, the principle is the same.

---

As a general debugging tip, liberally add `console.log` statements and watch your browser console (there are other ways, this is a basic debugging first-step), eg:

```
function hidePlayerControls() {
    console.log("hidePlayerControls() called");
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log("hidePlayerControls - interval triggered", isMouseMove);
        if (!isMouseMove) {
            hidePlayerControls();
        }
        isMouseMove=false;
    }, 4000);
```

to see just how many times this gets called

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response and for giving me a good headstart. I will go now and stare at the console in the hope of an epiphany